# Почему вызываемая onclick функция после срабатывания не меняет переменную и массив?

Tags: javascript, html

Скажите пожалуйста, как сделать чтобы массив менялся при нажатии на span!)

```
<span onclick="ne_rabotaet()">Нажатие ___</span>

<script>
    var a=[];

    function ne_rabotaet() {
        a[1]=5;
    }
    document.write(a[1]);
</script>
```

Ведь так все работает!

```
<span>Нажатие ___</span>

<script>
    var a=[];

    function rabotaet_ne_to() {
        a[1]=5;
    }
    rabotaet_ne_to();

    document.write(a[1]);
</script>
```

Comment: потому что `var a=[];` и `document.write(a[1]);` выполняются по готовности документа, `function lol() {a[1]=5;}` - при клике https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9 *не меняет переменную и массив?* - меняет. проверить можно `function lol() {
        a[1]=5; console.log(a);
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ очень простой - во втором примере вы запускаете lol() в скрипте, а в первом нет,  соответственно a[1] в первом случае не присваивается. Вывод сообщения происходит еще при загрузке страницы и без нажатия.
Т.е. здесь проблема не в onclick. При нажатии на span значение в функции присваиваивается, но вы же его не выводите.

Comment: Ага, но как сделать чтобы при нажатии на span первый вариант срабатывал?